# Add extension to libgdx project (gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I created a libgdx project with Gradle. Now I want to add an extension (bullet) to it. The project was created with `gdx-setup.jar`. How can I add bullet without creating a new project?

Answer (score 9):

You should edit your **build.gradle** file in the directory where the project was created, and add the bullet dependecy.

You can follow the libGDX wiki:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#bullet-gradle